# CollectionViewSource filtered DataGrid stops functioning after a few clicks

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

i read some articles about having `DataGrid` filtered automatically, using `CollectionViewSource`, so then i used it, but i found it will stop working after a few clicks. i would be nice if somebody could let me know what goes wrong.

work in .net 4.5.

following is a small demo that could reproduce the problem:

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dg" Margin="0,32,0,0"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="combo" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,5,80,0" SelectionChanged="combo_SelectionChanged"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Margin="0,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

c#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication9
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void cvs_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Item as Wrap) == null || combo.SelectedItem == null) return;
            if ((e.Item as Wrap).Int == (int)combo.SelectedItem)
                e.Accepted = true;
            else
                e.Accepted = false;
        }

        private void combo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            (dg.ItemsSource as ICollectionView).Refresh();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var oc = new ObservableCollection<Wrap>(from i in new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 4, 3, 7, 9, 8, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2 }
                                                    select new Wrap { Int = i });
            combo.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 9);
            var cvs = new CollectionViewSource();
            cvs.Source = oc;
            cvs.Filter += cvs_Filter;
            dg.ItemsSource = cvs.View;
            combo.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    class Wrap
    {
        public int Int { get; set; }
    }
}
```

result:

at the beginning:

[image]

it works fine. but after a few clicks:

[image]

couldn't get into event handler.

Comment: I can't say why this doesn't work - but I would say that if you're starting out with WPF, using the MVVM pattern is an absolute must.  Doing things like creating your source collections in the code-behind of your control will quickly become untenable.

Comment: @Andrew it's just a quick demo. in my real project, it comes with dynamic data and my wpf is not very good, so i feel more comfortable with code-behind.

Comment: i hope downvote could provide a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cvs` gets garbage collected.

so solution is to keep any reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

I also am not sure why your original code doesn't work, but you can be a bit more declarative about your filter. This code below does work (XAML is unchanged):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void combo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (dg.ItemsSource as ICollectionView).Refresh();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var oc = new ObservableCollection<Wrap>(from i in new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 4, 3, 7, 9, 8, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2 }
                                                select new Wrap { Int = i });
        combo.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 9);
        var cvs = new CollectionViewSource();
        cvs.Source = oc;
        cvs.View.Filter = o =>
            {
                if ((o as Wrap) == null || combo.SelectedItem == null) 
                    return false;
                return (o as Wrap).Int == ((int)(combo.SelectedItem));
            };
        dg.ItemsSource = cvs.View;
        combo.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}

class Wrap
{
    public int Int { get; set; }
}
```